# How to show that a monad is a functor and an applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

Monads are known to be theoretically a subset of functors and specifically applicative functors, even though it's not indicated in Haskell's type system.

Knowing that, given a monad and basing on `return` and `bind`, how to:

- derive `fmap`,
- derive `<*>` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, `fmap` is just `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, i.e. we want to transform the monadic action's result with a pure function. That's easy to write with do notation:

```
fmap f m = do
  a <- m
  return (f a)
```

or, written "raw":

```
fmap f m = m >>= \a -> return (f a)
```

This is available as [`Control.Monad.liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM).

`pure :: a -> f a` is of course `return`. `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is a little trickier. We have an action returning a function, and an action returning its argument, and we want an action returning its result. In do notation again:

```
mf <*> mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  return (f x)
```

Or, desugared:

```
mf <*> mx =
  mf >>= \f ->
  mx >>= \x ->
  return (f x)
```

Tada! This is available as [`Control.Monad.ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:ap), so we can give a complete instance of `Functor` and `Applicative` for any monad `M` as follows:

```
instance Functor M where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative M where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap
```

Ideally, we'd be able to specify these implementations directly in `Monad`, to relieve the burden of defining separate instances for every monad, such as with [this proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances). If that happens, there'll be no real obstacle to making `Applicative` a superclass of `Monad`, as it'll ensure it doesn't break any existing code. On the other hand, this means that the boilerplate involved in defining `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for a given `Monad` is minimal, so it's easy to be a "good citizen" (and such instances should be defined for any monad).

Comment: This answer is missing one important piece: proof that if a given `Monad` instance `m` does indeed satisfy the Monad laws, then the monadic definitions you provide for `fmap`, `pure` and `(<*>)` obey the Functor and Applicative laws.  All that Haskell enforces is that the types check.

Answer (score 10):

`fmap = liftM` and `(<*>) = ap`. Here are links to the source code for [liftM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) and [ap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap). I presume you know how to desugar do notation.