# Monad and Functor law for Monad and Functor type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor, category-theory

I am a somewhat experienced functional programmer, but I have always been confused by the statement “A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors” and the actual implementation of monads/functors in Haskell or other functional languages.

According to the Haskell Wiki,
https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor

```hs
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
```

##### Functor Laws

Functors must preserve identity morphisms

```
fmap id = id
```

Functors preserve composition of morphisms

```
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g
```

I understand this well, so no further explanation needed; however, when we uses the monad operator that is `>>=`, now we have Monad implementation and Monad laws

https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws

Here, I’m not questioning each implementation and rule. What I’m wondering is if we say “every Monad is an endofunctor because a monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors”, I expect a monad instance to satisfy the functor law, but in reality, it does not.

Or, although a monad is an endofunctor, the instance has 2 morphisms which are `>>=` and `fmap`. Do these two morphisms have independent laws?

I understand that the functor laws come from category theory and that a monad satisfies Monoid laws. But again, if a monad is an endofunctor, I don’t understand why it does not satisfy functor laws.

For intance,

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ [1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> [a]  // [2, 4, 6]
```

This code does not work if I change

```hs
  print $ [1, 2, 3] >>= id   // error "functor law" is not satisfied
```

Comment: I'm not really following, `>>=` and `<$>` are two different functions, with different laws, so I am not following why you assume the "functor law" is not satisfied.

Comment: The `Monad` type class has a superclass `Applicative` which in turn has a superclass `Functor`. So, you can't define `instance Monad M` without also having to define `instance Functor M`. Essentially, in Haskell monads are (endo)functors by definition. Also, functor laws are about `fmap`, while monad laws also involve `>>=` and `return`. These are distinct laws about distinct functions.

Comment: You are right, but 1.Every Monad is Endofunctor 2.Monad satisfies Monad laws 3 Endofunctor satisfies Functor laws. Therefore according to 1,2,3 Monad satisfies Functor laws, but in reality, it doesn't. Do you agree?

Comment: @chi, that fact `Applicative` class does not affect this quesion, and if you say "Essentially, in Haskell monads are (endo)functors by definition" why the monad code does not satify Functor laws? That is my quesion.

Comment: The slogan "all monads are functors" means: if `F` is a monad, then `fmap (id :: a->a) = (id :: F a -> F a)` and ... (`fmap` composition law). It simply means that if `F` is a monad, then its `fmap` satisfies the functor laws. This tells nothing about `>>=` or `return`. In other words, any functor has a `fmap` satisfying certain laws; monads are functors, so they also have a `fmap` satisfying the same laws.

Comment: @chi so is it like simply Monad instance has both operations that is `fmap` and `>>=`?

Comment: Morally, yes, but the practice is a little more cumbersome. In practice, inside `instance Monad F` you have to define `>>=`, only. However, if there is no `instance Functor F` elsewhere (with a `fmap`) you'll get a compiler error. So, you can't define `>>=` without also providing a `fmap`. (Even more confusingly, you'll also need `instance Applicative F` with its own `pure` and `<*>`. I wish all of this could be definable in the same instance instead of having to write three)

Comment: "*the instance has 2 morphisms which are >>= and fmap. Do these two morphisms have independent laws?*" - yes, they have separate laws. As a best practice, the two morphisms should be related, not independent, as otherwise the data structure is hard to understand and use, but they don't have to be.

Comment: "*“A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors”, so every monad is a functor*" - no, that does not follow. Please have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3870088/1048572), the tongue-in-cheek explanation of what a monad is plays on an even higher level of abstraction. While every instance of a monad is also an instance of a functor, that is unrelated to the "concept of monads" itself being an instance of a functor (in a different category).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. actually, I should have included that quesion (I did and for some reason deleted after the several edit), so even reading that answers, I will read again. So far, I feel better to have confirmed it's about 2 different morphisms. Thanks chi

Comment: Related: [*What is the relationship between bind and join?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56391291/2751851), and in particular the second part of [my answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403821/2751851).

Answer (score 11):

To begin with, there are two equivalent definitions of a monad. The first corresponds directly to the "monoid of endofunctors":

```
class Functor m => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

Here, we explicitly assume that `m` is an endofunctor. The monoidal "tensor product" of endofunctors is given by their composition. So `join` is an arrow from the "square" of `m` to `m`; it defines "multiplication" in our monoid. `return` is an arrow from the identity endofunctor to `m`; it defines monoidal unit. There are three monoidal laws in terms of `join` and `return` corresponding to the left/right unit and associativity.

The `Monad` definition used in Haskell uses bind `>>=` instead of `join`. A monad defined using bind is automatically an endofunctor, with `fmap` defined as:

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
liftM f ma = ma >>= return . f
```

The (relatively simple) monoidal laws from the first definition translate into the following laws:

```
return a >>= k = k a
ma >>= return = ma
ma >>= (\x -> k x >>= h) = (ma >>= k) >>= h
```

Functor laws for `liftM` follow from these laws. For instance, you can derive the composition law using these steps:

```
(liftM f . liftM g) ma 
= liftM f (ma >>= (return . g))
= (ma >>= (return . g)) >>= return . f
= ma >>= (\x -> ((return (g x)) >>= return . f))
= ma >>= (\x -> return (f (g x)))
= liftM (f . g) ma
```

Answer (score 8):

For theory purposes it's usually best to forget about `>>=`, we don't need it. The maths-style definition of these type classes looks thus:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
class Functor f => Applicative f where -- aka Monoidal
  pure :: a -> f a
  liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c  -- †
class Applicative m => Monad m where
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

(You could then go on to define `x>>=f = join (fmap f x)`, but that's just a matter of convenience.)

From this it should be clear that any discussion of `[1, 2, 3] >>= id` is pretty irrelevant for the question whether monads are functors. What it means for a monad to be a functor is right there in the class heads: `Monad` is a subclass of `Functor`. So any monad also has `fmap` available, and this `fmap` is still what needs to fulfill the functor laws, regardless of the fact that you now also have those fancier methods available.

---

†<sub>It's arguable whether `liftA2` or `<*>` are more mathematical. In principle we should be talking about the function with the signature `(a⊗b -> c) -> f a⊗f b -> f c`, but strictly speaking that only works with an *associative tensor product*. Haskell tuples approximate this, but only under awkward "`((a,b),c)` is isomorphic to `(a,(b,c))`" caveats. The nice thing about `<*>` is that curried functions have this associativity hidden under the hood, but the price to pay is that we need to deal with *exponential objects* and it all gets yet a bit more confusing. At any rate, I always found `liftA2` to be easier to understand than `<*>`.</sub>

Comment: I'll only add that the OP code `[1, 2, 3] >>= id`, which is the same as `join [1,2,3]`, is a type error since numbers are not lists.